# meaning of 'to give someone gloves'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Please help me to understand the meaning of the phrase in bold letters:

> I was not engaged to Mildred, but I lodged with her mother, and I sang duets with Mildred and **gave her gloves when it would run to it**, which was seldom. She was a dear, good girl, and I meant to marry her some day.

From 'Ebony Frame' by Edith Nesbit, 1893.

Comment: The "gave her gloves" would be meant literally, "when it would run to it" means "when finances allowed".

Comment: So, it means I bought her gloves when finances allowed?

Comment: But gloves are too insignificant material to bring up finance, I think. (Sorry my question seems to be stupid, but English is not my mother tongue.)

Comment: I think you're looking at that issue only from the perspective of modern culture where, in the main, gloves are no longer particularly fashionable, but merely utilitarian. If that were the case, it would seem strange, but in fashionable society in Victorian England, it was probably more like purchasing high-end designer fashion items in today's world (Prada shoes, Gucci handbags etc.)

Comment: In the preceding paragraph, the narrator is emphasizing his dire poverty which implies his inability to provide according to a minimum "acceptable" standard:  "...when you have **plumbed the depths of hard-up-ness** as a Fleet Street hack, a picker-up of unconsidered pars, a reporter, an unappreciated journalist; all callings utterly inconsistent with one's family feeling and one's direct descent from the Dukes of Picardy."

Comment: @bruisedreed I think you should write an answer, I think you've nailed it.

Comment: It seems giving someone a pair of gloves as gift was considered unlucky, or at least something was expected **in return** when gloves were given as gifts. See here for a reference  http://www.stylist.co.uk/life/13-strange-superstitions. There seem to be a few other UK sites mentioning this on the net.  I wonder if it was really a  deep rooted superstition at some time, but it may hold a clue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was not engaged to Mildred, but I lodged with her mother, and I sang
>   duets with Mildred and gave her gloves when it would run to it, which
>   was seldom. She was a dear, good girl, and I meant to marry her some
>   day.

This means that the narrator had an emotional attachment to Mildred, and expressed it by giving her an occasional gift. They would be taken as an expression of esteem, without crossing a boundary in an uncomfortable way.  The narrator wasn't ready to give Mildred a home, or even a ring, but he hoped to some day.

In that cultural context, women wore kid gloves when they went out of the house.  Gloves would have been a substantial gift but not extravagant.  Kid gloves wore out and needed to be replaced regularly.  I'm guessing the frequency would have been approximately the same as people replace running shoes nowadays -- on the order of pproximately every two years.

My German mother-in-law, born in the 1920's has a pair.  They are a work of art.